# Как переименовать пользователя в Windows 7

Tags: windows-7

Привет есть небольшая проблема-когда я устанавливал седьмую винду назвал пользователя Хабиб соответственно моя папка назвалась также. Но некоторые программы(Android SDK например) не могут работать с путями содержащими кириллицу. Я пробовал изменить имя пользователя-не помогло. Подскажите как поменять имя папки например на Khabih.

Заранее спасибо

Answer (score 2):

Проще, чем в реестре копаться - создать нового юзера, с именем на латинице (допустим, "Khabih"), установить прогу от его имени, и дать ей права запуска "для всех".

А ещё можно сделать юзера с перемещаемым профилем. Там можно руками задать расположение профильной папки.

Comment: Имя юзера, как советует nosensus, конечно можно! Но это не изменит имени рабочей папки, а просто создаст алиас, так что этот номер не пройдёт, и khamur(топикстартер)похоже, и сам в этом убедился.

Answer (score 1):

По идее это есть в реестре, но там есть еще кучу записей которые ссылаются на твоего старого пользователя, ты же не будешь все записи менять?)

Answer (score 1):

Переименовываешь профиль в управлении компьютером через mmc консоль, либо в панели управления, потом открываешь реестр и там по поиску, заменяешь все упоминания старой учетки, на название новой.

Еще один вариант, можно создать нового пользователя и скопировать старый профиль в новый.

Ну и можно опять же, создать нового пользователя в системе, а затем в реестре изменить один  параметр в ключике, вот в этом контейнереHKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\ProfileListищем свою учетку и меняем ProfileImagePath на нужную. Должно заработать, после LogOff (правда иногда создаются новые учетки и этот метод не всегда срабатывает).

Answer (score 0):

Start -> Control Panel -> User AccountsПо этому пути можно изменить, что угодно у пользователя. Только после смены не забудьте перезагрузиться либо сделать Log off

Comment: Это, к сожалению, не сработает с программами, которые не используют рекомендованные переменные %USER%, %CURRENT_USER% и т.п., а запоминают разименованные пути. Могут быть серьезные проблемы.

Comment: Да даже банальная командная строка не любит кириллицы в путях, хотя это для нее излечимо. У меня такое впечатление, что не нужно вообще пользоваться учетками с кириллицей, что, с одной стороны, ожидаемо: операционки и, считай, весь софт пишутся англоязычными.